# Very strange situation with Undefined index

Tags: php

php code:

```
 1. if (isset($data['city_id']))   
 2. {
 3.    $city_id = "city_id='". $data['city_id']. "', ";
 4. }
```

And I get:

> **Notice**: Undefined index: city_id  on line 3

How can this be?

Comment: Make sure there's no typo in `city_id`

Comment: `print_r($data)` and show all result

Comment: In $data array in this situation isn't index 'city_id' ant this is ok, so I use "isset": if (isset($data['city_id']))

Comment: Erase all 4 lines of code and type from scratch again and the problem will be gone. $5

Answer (score 0):

Just ran your code sample and it works perfectly, I do not get 'undefined index' error - taking us to the big apple

```
<?php
$data['city_id']='New York';
if (isset($data['city_id']))   
{
 $city_id = "city_id='". $data['city_id']. "', ";
 echo $city_id;
 }

?>
```

output: city_id='New York',

Surely, without the `$data['city_index']='New York';` I just get a blank screen, as the `if` condition is not met - no errors.

Comment: Surely, without the `$data['city_index']='New York';` I just get a blank screen, as the if condition is not met - no errors.

Comment: when You write:

Comment: when You write:
$data['city_id']='New York';
not necessary use: if (isset($data['city_id']))   , 
because You know exactly that this index is.
I always use  "isset" and this helped me. But now I have this notice.